# How to preview a ListView using Xamarin.Forms xaml editor

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I'm implementing a ListView in Xamarin.Forms with custom cells, but I can't see what I'm doing since the preview shows an empty list and re-building every time is simple too time consuming. I can't even see a simple TextCell..

How can I see the preview of my cells in the editor? This is my xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ContentPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNamespace"
    x:Class="MyNamespace.MyAppPage">
<ContentPage.Content>

    <ListView x:Name="myList">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextCell Text="Preview?" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>

</ContentPage.Content>
```

Note: I am using Visual Studio 2017 for Mac.

---

**2nd Part**

OK so I tried using BindingContext but I don't understand well the usage of this property. This is my updated XAML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ContentPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNamespace;assembly:MyNamespace"
    BindingContext="{x:Static local:MusicSeed.Model}"
    x:Class="MyNamespace.MyAppPage">

    <ContentPage.Content>

        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Tracks}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextCell Text="{Binding Name}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>

    </ContentPage.Content>

</ContentPage>
```

And this is where I have the data, *MusicSeed.cs*:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public static class MusicSeed
    {
        public static readonly MusicSeedModel Model = new MusicSeedModel();  
    }

    public class MusicSeedModel
    {
        public readonly MusicTrack[] Tracks =
        {
            new MusicTrack("Track 01"),
            new MusicTrack("Track 02"),
            new MusicTrack("Track 03"),
            new MusicTrack("Track 04"),
        }; 
    }
}
```

The result is this error thrown by the XAML editor:

> No static member found for local:MusicSeed.Model

I tried changing `Tracks` as static but nothing changed. Also rebuilt the solution, the error disappeared but the preview is still empty. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to provide some kind of `BindingContext` for rows to be rendered during design time.  There is an [awesome article](https://montemagno.com/xamarinforms-xaml-previewer-design-time-data/) by James Montemagno that explains how to do just that.

Another recommended article to refer would be [this one on Xamarin Help](https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-forms-previewer/)

[image]

**EDIT 1:**

Your XAML is correct, but the view-model is wrong. You can only bind to properties. Try changing you declaration to following:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class MusicSeed
    {
        public static MusicSeedModel Model { get; } = new MusicSeedModel();
    }

    public class MusicSeedModel
    {
        public MusicTrack[] Tracks { get; } =
            {
                new MusicTrack("Track 01"),
                new MusicTrack("Track 02"),
                new MusicTrack("Track 03"),
                new MusicTrack("Track 04"),
            };
    }

    public class MusicTrack
    {
        public string Name { get; }

        public MusicTrack(string v)
        {
            this.Name = v;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This article seems to be for Xamarin Studio, but the question is about Visual Studio. Will this work for VS, too?

Comment: According to this [XamarinHelp article](https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-forms-previewer/) it does.

Comment: @dennis-schröer : Also, `Visual Studio for Mac` is just an updated version of `Xamarin Studio`

Comment: @G.Sharada I added your suggestion but it still not workin, most likely I am missing something. I edited the question if you wanna take a look.

Comment: @josemigallas : I have updated the answer. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks! Important step after using your solution was to **rebuild all** again!

Answer (score 1):

You can't. If you are using MVVM framework, your code still needs to be generated / Build.

An Alternative is to use  [Xamarin Live Player](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/live/install/)  Which Can Build Lists On your actual device for android and ios

FYI: Currently while answering this questions it's on Alpha